# Jenkins build failure : Failed to create /var/lib/tomcat8/.m2

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am currently trying to setup jenkins build for my maven project. I have completed all the required configurations. But when trying to build the project it says ERROR: Failed to create /var/lib/tomcat8/.m2 where var/lib/tomcat8 is my tomcat's home directory. Can someone please help me on this error?

Comment: Check for the permissions in that directory

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava That's it. Many thanks. the tomcat folder was lacking all permissions.